Unable to unsave posts when showing them again, or even just after being refreshed, using the left side icon
With posts being shown again after being saved, or even just after a browser Web page refresh, I'm now unable to unsave them (with Microsoft Edge, version 131.0.2903.63, on Windows 10) by clicking the "Save/Unsave" left side icon (shown within a blue oval in the image below). For example, this failed with 4 posts that I've tried from my saved list, with the developer console of Set of all versus some showing the following:



As shown with the right side green rectangle, the last 3 error messages, i.e., issues with jquery.min having a return code of 400, each occurred when I tried clicking the icon to unsave the post.
However, this does work properly if you click that icon to save and then unclick the icon again without refreshing/reloading the page. Unsaving a post after the page is displayed again, or even just redisplayed, has been working for me as recently as of several days ago, so this appears to be a recent issue.
Fortunately, in the Profile Saves list, clicking the right side item menu and then choosing the Unsave option does work, apparently for all of the posts. Nonetheless, I would appreciate also being able to use the icon on the posts at any time.

Well thought you click something else, if that's the ordinary button then it should be easy to reproduce for those having old Saved posts.

Also, some debug without testing myself, "400 Bad Request" most likely means the ID of the post isn't being sent to the server, you can verify this by going to the network tab of the dev tools, and check the request headers.

Update: I'm unable to Unsave the example question you gave, so it's not related to the Save being old, it's something else.

Oh my this happens for me on all posts on all sites, can you unsave any post? If so please give link and I'll try as well. /cc @RandomPerson (it let me unsave only if I don't reload)

@ShadowWizard I checked this on Android after reading the post and everything seemed to work. I could save and unsave the post given in the question on https://maths.stackexchange.com on both Android and Chrome on WIndows 10. But after logging into Edge, the problem arose ... and now, it is also broken on Android and Chrome on Windows 10

@ShadowWizard I did some more testing to confirm that I'm not able to unsave any post when I display it again, or even after a screen refresh. Thus, we both have the same issue. I've updated my question here to clarify that it only works when the unsave is done by the icon while still on the original page.

@PeterJames perhaps the browser had cached version of the JS, and after it loaded the new, broken, code it started to fail.

@ShadowWizard Very bizarre. After using your workaround, it all works nicely until I reload the page by clicking the browser reload button.

@PeterJames FYI, my question does state that even just doing a refresh, i.e., a browser reload, as you describe, is sufficient for the left side icon to no longer unsave the post when it's clicked.

@starball Note: Although that other question's results are somewhat similar to what I describe above, that post is about the behavior from clicking the "Save button in the review". My post is about clicking the Save/Unsave icon on the post itself. Also, the other question is from just over 2 years ago, while the behavior I described started just before I posted, i.e., about 4 days ago. In addition, note that another duplicate of my question was posted fairly shortly after mine at Cannot remove a post from saves from the Q&A page, but was then closed as a duplicate of this one.

Please reopen this post. This bug started happening only a few days ago. The bug report post this was marked as a duplicate of was made more than two years ago, meaning it's not a duplicate. We should reopen this question to track this bug report separately.

Stack Exchange: "All your saving are belong to us!"

@DionWilliams ah, so it's related to change done in Teams?

@ShadowWizard It's a regression from an accessibility fix I made to the public platform's Save buttons last week. I'll post an answer once the fix has been reviewed, tested and deployed.

Sorry for that! I made a couple of accessibility fixes to the Save / Unsave buttons last week to add accessible labels (so that they could be read by screen readers) and to remove the aria-pressed attribute, which didn't belong on these buttons.
In doing so, I caused a regression here where the state of the post being saved or unsaved was read incorrectly on a fresh page load, always reporting the post as unsaved. I'd tested the buttons without refreshing the page in-between, missing this.
This should now be fixed and this part of the code has been covered with regression tests so hopefully similar issues here are less likely to happen in future.

Fix confirmed. While here, something rather minor, but, well I'd better try. The other icons (vote arrows, timeline icon) change color when hovered, but the Saves icon doesn't. Is this on purpose? If not, is there a point starting a feature request asking to add that? Thanks.

@ShadowWizard Good spot. I think a feature request for that would be worthwhile. I'm not familiar with the design of these bits, so I'm not sure if it's on purpose or not.

Ah turns out it's already reported.

This appears to be cross network bug that affects all posts that you Save, regardless when you Saved them.
As a workaround, we can also unsave from the profile page:

This still works.

This doesn't work on the post itself because the client side code fails to send ?isUndo=true querystring parameter, which the server is expecting. When the parameter will be added back, the unsave will work again.
